# Some applications stop using LD_PRELOAD shortly after starting

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I have been experimenting with LD_PRELOAD and specifically, I wanted to replace the implementations of malloc and free with my own, which prints information about the number of bytes allocated in the case of malloc and the address freed in the case of free.

Unfortunately, my experiments have not been successful with many programs, including Firefox, Discord, MS Teams, and Telegram. Although these programs initially use my version of memory allocators, they soon stop using it.

Initially, I tried running the command in the terminal:
 `LD_PRELOAD=<my_library_name.so> ./<program>`

However, I later found out that for some of the programs mentioned above, <program> was not the actual binary file, but rather a script that runs the binary. I then tried to locate the actual binary files and run them, but the result was still the same.

My question is whether there is a way to have LD_PRELOAD propagate to all subprocesses or if there is another way to ensure that my implementations are used consistently. It is not just about seeing logs of malloc and free usage, which I can achieve using ltrace, but rather about experimenting and learning something. I would like to understand exactly what is causing my problem and how to solve it.

Example logs from running Discord:

```
> LD_PRELOAD=./my_malloc.so /snap/discord/151/usr/share/discord/Discord

allocated: 32 bytes, at: 0x5578afe902a0
allocated: 32 bytes, at: 0x5578afe902d0
allocated: 32 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90300
allocated: 2 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90330
allocated: 5 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90350
free at: 0x5578afe90350
allocated: 120 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90370
allocated: 12 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90350
allocated: 792 bytes, at: 0x5578afe903f0
allocated: 104 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90710
allocated: 1328 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90780
allocated: 208 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90cc0
allocated: 424 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90da0
allocated: 96 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90f50
allocated: 80 bytes, at: 0x5578afe90fc0
Discord 0.0.26
Starting app.
Starting updater.
2023-04-19T21:31:47.995Z [Modules] Modules initializing
2023-04-19T21:31:47.995Z [Modules] Distribution: remote
2023-04-19T21:31:47.995Z [Modules] Host updates: enabled
2023-04-19T21:31:47.995Z [Modules] Module updates: enabled
2023-04-19T21:31:47.996Z [Modules] Module install path: /home/test_user/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules
2023-04-19T21:31:47.996Z [Modules] Module installed file path: /home/test_user/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/installed.json
2023-04-19T21:31:47.996Z [Modules] Module download path: /home/test_user/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/pending
2023-04-19T21:31:48.139Z [Modules] No updates to install
2023-04-19T21:31:48.139Z [Modules] Checking for host updates.
[89694:0419/233148.276510:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, format: BGRA_8888, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
[89694:0419/233148.276681:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, format: BGRA_8888, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
[89694:0419/233148.276749:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, format: BGRA_8888, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
[89694:0419/233148.276813:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, format: BGRA_8888, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
```

As you can see at the beginning there are my logs, but right after "Discord 0.0.26" my library with malloc and free suddenly stopped being used.

Comment: Environment variables automatically propagate to all child processes and their decendants. So unless one of the children is resetting `LD_PRELOAD`, it should stick.

Comment: If `ltrace` is showing you the `malloc`/`free` you are interested in, then have a look at its implementation. It has to deal with the same problem. (`ltrace` is not a OS mechanism) There is also no guarantee that all memory allocation goes through `malloc`. For example I wouldn't be surprised if apps like that used custom allocators backed e.g. by `mmap` calls.

Comment: ... but it is entirely plausible that some processes *are* dropping environment variables when they launch children.  Doing so is a good security practice -- for protection against exactly the kind of thing you're trying to do, for example.

Comment: Adding to @JohnBollinger's point, there's not much you can (easily*) do if a process makes changes to its environment and re-exec's itself.  \* - It **is** your OS, with **your** kernel and **your** libraries, so if you **really** want to you can work around just about anything a process tries to do.